# ASP .NET Core: Routing. Multiple categories in url at begining

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0, asp.net-core-routing

I have to pass user requests from URLs like:

```
site.com/events/2017/06/wwdc.html
```

or more common:

```
site.com/category1/subcategory1/subcategory2/...../subcategoryN/page-title.html
```

e.g.

```
site.com/cars/tesla/model-s/is-it-worth-it.html
```

to `ArticlesController` with action `Index(string title)` or something like that.

At compile time I don't know how many segments I will have. But I know, that URLs will ends with `/{pageTitle}.html`. The main problem is that default asp.net core routing doesn't allow me to write something like `{*}/pageTitle.html`

Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible and you almost did it.

The route is

```
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "all",
                template: "{*query}",
                defaults: new
                {
                    controller = "Index",
                    action = "ArticlesController"
                });
        });
```

**EDIT**: `template: "{*query:regex(.+/.+\\.html$)}"` will ensure that at least one category is given and that the title ends with .html

And in the controller's action:

```
    public IActionResult Index(string query)
    {
        string[] queryParts = query.Split(new char[] { '/' });
        string title = queryParts[queryParts.Length - 1];
        string[] categories = queryParts.Take(queryParts.Length - 1).ToArray();

        // add your logic about the title and the categories

        return View();
    }
```

See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing):

> Dedicated conventional routes often use catch-all route parameters
>   like {*article} to capture the remaining portion of the URL path. This
>   can make a route 'too greedy' meaning that it matches URLs that you
>   intended to be matched by other routes. Put the 'greedy' routes later
>   in the route table to solve this.

Comment: that route will catch all requests, not only things like `category/title.html`
The only thing can help me is put this rule at the end...

Thanks

Comment: This route must be place at the end, right.
You can filter things like `category/title.html` by applying a regular expression in the filter. `template: "{*query:regex(.+/.+\\.html$)}",` will work perfect for your needs ;) (you can also upvote my answer if it works well :-p)

Comment: Right, I did not know that. I am new on StackOverflow too.